# JS - http request file contains js variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I have a http request in a nodejs project to get a file which is a javascript file.

e.g. a.js:

```
var a = 'i am a.js';
var b = 'please convert me to js';
```

axios get function:

```
axios.get('a.js').then((response) => {
    let data = response.data
    // data should have var a and b as a STRING type
})
```

As I'm using javascript to get this file, how can I convert this file to simple javascript variable? Thankyou!

Comment: haha, I hope the backend return an object too but I can't XD!! That is a old backend service.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `require('a.js')` instead, if it's on the same server.
There you should use `exports.a = "i am a.js"`

If not, you could use the eval function to run the javascrip code. `eval(data)`